# Can I use regex in a DynamoDB query?

Tags: regex, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use regex when I query a table. I tried to use it under `KeyConditionExpression`, but it isn't valid. Is there any way to do it with DynamoDB?

For example, my primary key is a string, and I want to get all the items that start with an `A`. The `KeyConditionExpression` expression would look like `"someKey = /^A/"`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No. DynamoDB does **not** support regex.

The closest thing is `CONTAINS` and `NOT_CONTAINS`.

See [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html).